# Capture stream from camera and put it on canvas with Ionic on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to capture a stream from the camera, and either:

- use this stream as a source for video tag on the HTML page
- use this stream (frames) as a source for canvas

I've already written an application that, when used on the desktop in the browser, was capturing camera and playing it in video tag, but apparently this solution does now work by default when I deployed my app to the Android phone.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, were you able to find some solution for this? Currently, I am looking for something similar.

Comment: venkatakrishnan and @dragonfly did you guys managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Both features(Options) are possible : 
use this stream as a source for video tag on the HTML page
use this stream (frames) as a source for canvas

Using ionic with FileTransfer ,  Camera plugin you can easily stream the details of your data(bytes, frames, images,text) inside a canvas which is 100 percent possible as cordova is an extension of HTML5 of mobile.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit (maybe with code snippets)? What exact plugins I need? Did you mean that https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/ can be configured to transfer the stream? So far, when I use this plugin, application i launching camera application that enables taking pictures, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using cordova.plugins.permission below is an example

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: false,video: { facingMode: { exact: "user" },frameRate: { ideal: 30, max: 30 }}}).then(function(stream) {
      // Create video element to display the captured frames
      var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
      videoElement.srcObject = stream;
      videoElement.play()
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Error playing video:', error);
        });

      // Create canvas element to draw the video frames onto
      var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
      var canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

      // Set the canvas size to match the video element
      videoElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        canvasElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
        canvasElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
      });

      // Draw each video frame onto the canvas element
      function draw() {
        canvasContext.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }

      // Start drawing the video frames onto the canvas
      videoElement.addEventListener('play', function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      });

      // Add the video and canvas elements to the page
      var containerElement = document.createElement('div');
      containerElement.style.position = 'fixed';
      containerElement.style.top = '0';
      containerElement.style.left = '0';
      containerElement.style.right = '0';
      containerElement.style.bottom = '0';

      canvasElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      canvasElement.style.top = '0';
      canvasElement.style.left = '0';
      canvasElement.style.right = '0';
      canvasElement.style.bottom = '0';

      containerElement.appendChild(videoElement);
      containerElement.appendChild(canvasElement);
      document.body.appendChild(containerElement);
```